# Convert Spring Boot and OAuth2 client from using Client Credentials flow to Authorization Code Grant flow

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

I have been struggling while trying to create a sample client that uses the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant flow.

I am able to successfully use the Client Credentials flow but when I try to use the Authorization Code flow I do not get redirected to the correct uri.

When calling the OAuth2RestTmplate.exchange method, I get a redirect exception in the RestTemplate.doExecute(...) method.  It is thrown from the finally clause.
The response is null, but the if is not stopping it.

```
finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
```

I still get prompted for login and authorization, but am not directed to the response containing the data.  I am just redirected back to the client home page.  The same call from Postman using the authorization code flow with the same client credentials is successful so I know the client registration is correct.

I could use another pair of eyes to see what I'm missing.   Thanks in Advance!  Below are my code excerpts.

**Working client using oauth2 client credentials flow:**

**Client App**:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ClientExampleClientCredentials extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientExampleClientCredentials.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ClientExampleClientCredentials.class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.apiUrl}")
    private String apiUrl;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.scope}")
    private List<String> scopes;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;


    /**
     * Example of using the OAuth2RestTemplate to access external resources
     *
     * The OAuth2RestTemplate takes care of exchanging credentials with the auth server, as well as adding the
     * bearer token to each request to the FHIR services.
     *
     */
    @RequestMapping("/ex-1")
    public String retrievePatientByIdUsingRestTemplate(@RequestParam String id) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(getClientCredentialsResourceDetails(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext());
        ResponseEntity<String> response = oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange(apiUrl + "/Patient/" + id, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
        String responseBody = response.getBody();
        return responseBody;
    }

    private ClientCredentialsResourceDetails getClientCredentialsResourceDetails() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();

        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setScope(scopes);

        return clientCredentialsResourceDetails;
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            clientId: client_id
            clientSecret: secret
            apiUrl: http://localhost:8080/testData/data
            accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/test-auth/token  
            scope: system/*.read
```

This works great authenticating me and then redirecting to my service url.  However, The Authorization Code flow is not working.

**Broken client using oauth2 authorization code flow:**

**Client App:**

```
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ClientExampleAccessToken extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientExampleAccessToken.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ClientExampleAccessToken.class);
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
package org.ihc.clinical.controller;

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @Value(("${security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri}"))
    private String userAuthorizationUri;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.apiUrl}")
    private String apiUrl;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.redirectUri}")
    private String redirectUri;


    @RequestMapping("/ex-1")
    public String retrievePatientByIdUsingRestTemplate(@RequestParam String empi) {

        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource = resource();
        String path = apiUrl + "/Patient/" + empi;
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext());

        ***/*error occurs here in RestTemplate.doExcute.  error:org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: 
        A redirect is required to get the users approval */***  
        ResponseEntity<String> response = oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);

        //AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider provider = new //AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
        //Token Request
        //AccessTokenRequest request = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
        //String code = provider.obtainAuthorizationCode(resource, request);
        //request.setAuthorizationCode(code);
        //OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = //provider.obtainAccessToken(resource, request);

        //Token Response
        //String tokenValue = oAuth2AccessToken.getValue();
        //return tokenValue;
    }

    //Call when ready to send token Request
    private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails authorizationCodeResourceDetails = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setUserAuthorizationUri(userAuthorizationUri);
        //authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setScope(scopes);
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(redirectUri);

        return authorizationCodeResourceDetails;
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        clientId: clientid
        clientSecret: secret
        accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/test-auth/token
        userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/test-auth/authorize
        apiUrl: http://localhost:8080/test-fhir-cdr/data
        redirectUri: http://localhost:8080/test-examples-access-token
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the client_credential flow!! I have been struggling to do so.

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote for the client credentials flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution here: https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

I needed to add the below code to the controller:

```
 @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2Context;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate getOauth2RestTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2Context);
    }
```

Then call getOauth2RestTemplate() like below:

```
@RequestMapping("/ex-1")
public String retrievePatientByIdUsingRestTemplate(@RequestParam String empi) {

String path = apiUrl + "/Patient/" + empi;
OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = getOauth2RestTemplate();

ResponseEntity<String> response = oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);

return response.getBody();
```

}